# Update Firebase child node in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I am a currently writing my first Swift app and I am trying to implement a payment option using Stripe. After reading many articles including questions asked here in StackOverflow the best advise I could find is to use Firebase Cloud Functions, as I am already using Firebase Realtime Database as my backend.

The Stripe Firebase Cloud Function examples found here are exactly what I need to get started.

[Stripe Firebase Cloud Functions examples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js)

For example the function below registers a Stripe user whenever a new user is registered in Firebase base.

Firebase Cloud Function: `createStripeCustomer`

```
// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});
```

The following line of the function above writes the returned Stripe customer_id to Cloud Firestore, my app is using Realtime Firebase, **what changes can I make to the following line (I don't know any JavaScript)?**

```
admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id})
```

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your response, I suppose my focus is Swift, I have only been coding in Swift for approx 1 year and therefore not ready to learn another language just yet. I simply want those functions to work with Firebase Realtime Database to enable payment processing in my Swift app :/

Comment: I don't think you should be afraid of learning a new language.  Swift is going to have set you up with the fundamentals of a new language and it is something you're going to need to make a functional app anyway.  Javascript (while not my favorite) is a very approachable language -- not because it's particularly readable -- but because it's got a ton of learning modules.  I think Frank is right.  Maybe start with the basics first.  :)

Comment: The function is written in JavaScript. If you want to modify it, you'll have to know that language enough to make the modification. If you want someone to make the modification for you, Stack Overflow is not the right site for that kind of help.

Comment: That said: the code used to be based on the realtime database. See this branch for a version of that: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen